# One key Emacs LaTeX compilation?

Tags: emacs, latex

Are there any Emacs gurus out there who can tell me how to bind C-B to Auctex's LaTeX compilation? This is, instead of C-c C-c RET. I'm on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C-c is a general prefix key which means it is hard to 'shorten' it.

You could alternatively bind you favorite function to one of the function keys. Hitting C-h k (for help on key) followed by C-c C-c reveals that the function bound to the key is TeX-command-master.  So you could try something like

```
(global-set-key "^X9" 'TeX-command-master)
```

to bind this function to F9.

Answer (score 9):

Dirk's answer works, but you still need to type RET after you type the function key. I haven't figure out how to invocate, say, Latex command from TeX-command-master specifically. So my hack for now use keyboard macro:

```
(defun my-tex-mode-hook ()
(local-set-key (kbd "<f5>") (kbd "C-c C-c C-j")))

(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook 'my-tex-mode-hook)
```

(You need to use local-set-key instead of global-set-key since C-c C-c C-j might do something unexpected in other modes!)

Then you have a truly one keypress solution.

Comment: This answer, though more of a workaround, achieves the objective better than the other. I added "C-x C-s" before the other keys so it would also save without asking.

Comment: Works perfectly, but it is kind of a hack. The variable LaTeX-command stores the command that is executed by C-c C-c C-j. I'm a lisp noob, so how can I replace `(kbd "C-c C-c C-j")` with something like `(execute LaTeX-command)`?